# Displaying two Images at a time with Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, ajax, image, gallery, modal-dialog

So I'm basically trying to display a book-layout in a [modal box](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) with images; that is, I want to load two images at the same time, side by side in the same window. It would look something like this:

<< |0.jpg| |1.jpg| >>

<< |2.jpg| |3.jpg| >>

<< |4.jpg| |5.jpg| >>

etc etc...
Viewers would be able to click NEXT and PREVIOUS to go back and forth between the pairs of images.

Is there a way to do this, or is it way too much trouble to bother with?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are the images stored? Are they always numbered 0.jpg, 1.jpg ,2.jpg?

Comment: Yes. They'd be numbered 000.jpg 001.jpg 002.jpg etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to physically combine two images on your server and send them out as a single image to the user, couldn't you just have something like:

```
<div class="book">
   <div class="leftpage"><img src="0.jpg"></div>
   <div class="rightpage"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

with the appropriate navigation links and whatnot inserted as well.

Comment: I certainly can do that, but I was hoping to make it more like an image replacement gallery [ http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/img-replacement.html ], but two at a time. I may end up having to do it the way you suggested though.

Comment: No reason you can't do it as in that example - just replace two images instead of one. Just a bit of extra client-side processing to figure out which of the two thumbnail images you clicked on, and update the two larger images.